# conda activate does not seem to have any effect on windows

Tags: windows, conda

I create and activate a conda environment on Windows 10. I don't see any indicator that the environment is active. Also `which python` and `which pip` don't report any relevance to the activated environment.

```
PS C:\Users\xxx> conda create -n tp_assist
Channels:
 - defaults
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\xxx\.conda\envs\tp_assist



Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate tp_assist
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate

PS C:\Users\xxx> conda activate tp_assist
PS C:\Users\xxx> which python
/c/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python
PS C:\Users\xxx> which pip
/c/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/pip

PS C:\Users\xxx> conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                     C:\ProgramData\miniconda3
tp_assist                C:\Users\xxx\.conda\envs\tp_assist
```